# How to audit azure DevOps services and monitor releases?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps instance where I am trying to control and monitor who is doing releases. So, who pressed the button to do the release and what releases have happened.

I tried in Audit options, but it is not satisfying my requirement.

What is the best way to get what I am looking for?

Thanks in advance…

Comment: Are you trying to monitor a single release pipeline or many?

Comment: I have too many releases approximately thousand releases.

Comment: not releases. How many release **pipelines** are you trying to monitor

Comment: I do have hundreds of release pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's a little unclear what you mean by CONTROL

If you are needing to tighten control of which users are allowed to initiate releases outside of a CI/CD pipeline, this is something you would use the built in object permissions for release pipelines.

#### I've organized our release pipelines into folders

Each of these folders is treated as an object upon which permissions can be set.
[image]
[image]

### For MONITORING the release pipelines

Again, I tend to just use the `All Pipelines` folder which gives a list of the releases that happened ordered by date. That view lists the pipeline and gives the users Avatar, which is enough to know who created the release.

[image]

### Also

There are some out-of-the-box widgets that you can put on your dashboard, but I've found them to be unhelpful on the whole. Not to mention that if you have 100's of pipelines you will want to have something reading from your list of pipelines via REST api and pushing those widgets onto the dashboard via the REST api so that you don't need to manage them all "by hand" through the UI. **Then** if you're going to get into using the REST api, you might as well write your own tool to report the information you need (and possibly turn it into a widget others can consume from the marketplace). I haven't found anything very effective on reporting/summarizing the collection of release pipelines from the marketplace, but there may be something squirreled away in there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Josh! I am looking for the process to generate a report which shows who has what access and who is triggering the releases and who is approving  those actions?